# Is it possible to just detect (not change) current brightness level on iOS screen?

Tags: ios, user-interface, styles, switching

Is it possible to just detect (not change) current brightness level on iOS screen? For example, I am trying to set a certain brightness value at which the UI/styles may change based on the current context. Sort of like responsive stylesheet switching, but instead of using dimensions I want to change per brightness.

If you have heard of this on any mobile operating system, please let me know that as well. Thank you for your time!

I am asking this to propose a project to an engineer, thus my limited knowledge of the code. Just looking for a yes or not possibility. I need to understand the feasibility before I propose it and have not found information on this elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify since you seem confused between getters and setters:

To read either:

```
float brightness = [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness];
```

or

```
float brightness = [UIScreen mainScreen].brightness;
```

To change:

```
float brightness = XX;
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:brightness];
```

or

```
float brightness = XX;
[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = brightness;
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't that set the brightness though?

Comment: No, that is accessing the getter (read). If you want to set it you'd call [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:value]